# V1.0.1.70 – Launch bug causes crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, connectivity

If you start the app with no internet connection it will crash the app.

To recreate completely close the app, turn on Airplane mode with no wifi, then launch the app.

Comment: Reproduced on v1.0.1.70. Actually, I also crashed the one on the App Store (v1.0.0) this morning. It crashes when there's no network connection on the first launch of the app.

Comment: Reproduced here too. Was anybody else not notified of an update from 1.0.0.67? ( bug didn't exist there btw)

Comment: Man, I want 1.0.0.67 back. This one lost features like comment reply, doesn't have the reputation fix for 1000-9999.... Maybe that's why we weren't notified of it

Comment: Installing the new version from App Store now while keeping the Alpha version 1.0.0.67 edit: interesting, the app store got version 1.0.0 from May 1st! :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you give me more details. Logged in, anonymous, first run?

Comment: I am previously logged in, it is not the first run but it is only when the App has been completely closed and then opened when no internet connection is available. I am using a iPhone 5 16GB - Black. Version : 7.1.1(11D201), Model : MD297B/A, Carrier : EE. You might think I'm crazy giving you the colour of my device but I have had a bug that really did only affect white iPhones.

Comment: @StePrescott Nothing happening for me at all and nothing showing up in Crashlytics.  Can you send your crash logs to iosapp@stackexchange.com?

Comment: @BrianNickel Sent :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this bug is actually fixed.  I was just confused.  If you download from the beta channel (which claims the latest is 0.1.70, that's a lie) you will get release 1.0.1.1 (also funny because this is a later release).  That build should not crash.

P.S. We are aware of the releases not notifying you right now and I have my top men working on it.

Comment: Works now :-) thanks.

Comment: "Your top men"? Secret group, I guess? :D